# Npm not installed

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I recently downloaded node.js from nodejs.org and installed it correctly on windows, from gitbash I ran node -v,it gave me a version number,but when I ran npm -v, I get bunch of error message like these;

```
Internal/module/cjs/loader.js:330
Throw err;

Error: cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\nom-registry-fetch\node_modules\fighy-pudding\index.js'. 
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

And other bunch of errors...

How do I fix these please

Comment: What error messages do you get?

Comment: "I get bunch of error message" does not help us, but *showing* us the messages you get does. Edit your question to include these as plain text so we can see what's going on.

Comment: Do not post photos of your screen or even screenshots of the errors. Copy the error messages and paste them as text in the question.

Comment: I've voted to reopen this question-- however, could you please include the other errors as well?  It will be helpful to the community.  If it helps, you can preface text lines with the `>` character to put them in a inline box.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, i tried alot of replies, still ended up the same. 
I reinstalled windows and installed the same nodejs.exe i downloaded and npm was installed...lol